# Py 3: tkinter frames, coding inside or outside of frame classes

Tags: python, class, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

So I'm creating a GUI mathematical program for school using python 3 and tkinter where we have to ask the user what formula they want to use (add, sub, multiply, divide) and then ask 10 questions show a results page once all 10 questions have been answered on that page and then start over again in a loop. i want to create 4 different difficulties

Easy = Range between (1,9), medium = Range between (10,24), Hard = Range between (25,50), Insane = Range Between (51,100)

I've created the gui so far as shown below but want to know if I'm going to organize the working out of the equations in the page classes or somehow outside of the class. im pretty new to python/tkinter I've never used it before but just learnt what i have so far off youtube hours and hours of watching.

All i want to know is where to go from now with where to place the equation code/formula. once i know where to stick it ill be away.

(all code below if you copy and paste into python 3 and save it will instantly work. any problems will be indents from the copy and paste due to how i copied it all into this chat.

Any issues you see below please feel free to point out. As I said I'm pretty new I Google didn't really help as I didn't quite know what to type in to find it.

kind regards

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk #css kind of thing for tkinter
import random

difficulty = []

LARGE_FONT = ("Times New Roman", 25)
MEDIUM_FONT = ("Times New Roman", 15)
SMALL_FONT = ("Times New Roman", 10)


###Base Code For Pages


class ourprogramclass(tk.Tk):

    def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="mathsicon.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Mathematic Equation program")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, AdditionPage, SubtractionPage, MultiplicationPage, DivisionPage ):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


###Page Classes front page



class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text = "Mathmatics Problems Quiz", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text = "Mathematic Equation program", font=MEDIUM_FONT)
        label3 = tk.Label(self, text = "Select Your Operation and Difficulty Level", font=SMALL_FONT)
        label1.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        label2.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        label3.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Addition Equations", font=MEDIUM_FONT,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(AdditionPage)).pack(fill=X)
        label = Label(self,text="").pack()
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text = "Subtraction Equations", font=MEDIUM_FONT,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(SubtractionPage)).pack(fill=X)
        label = Label(self,text="").pack()        
        button3 = tk.Button(self, text = "Multiplication Equations", font=MEDIUM_FONT,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MultiplicationPage)).pack(fill=X)
        label = Label(self,text="").pack()
        button4 = tk.Button(self, text = "Division Equations", font=MEDIUM_FONT,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(DivisionPage)).pack(fill=X)
        label = Label(self,text="").pack()

        label4 = tk.Label(self, text = "Select Difficulty", font=LARGE_FONT).pack()

        def checkbutton_value1():
            if (var1.get()):
                var2.set(0)
                var3.set(0)
                var4.set(0)
                del difficulty[:]
                difficulty.append(1)
                print (difficulty[0])

        def checkbutton_value2():
            if(var2.get()):
                var1.set(0)
                var3.set(0)
                var4.set(0)
                del difficulty[:]
                difficulty.append(2)
                print (difficulty[0])

        def checkbutton_value3():
            if(var3.get()):
                var1.set(0)
                var2.set(0)
                var4.set(0)
                del difficulty[:]
                difficulty.append(3)
                print (difficulty[0])

        def checkbutton_value4():
            if(var4.get()):
                var1.set(0)
                var2.set(0)
                var3.set(0)
                del difficulty[:]
                difficulty.append(4)
                print (difficulty[0])

        var1 = IntVar()
        dif_button1 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Easy", variable=var1, command=checkbutton_value1).pack()

        var2 = IntVar()
        dif_button2 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Medium", variable=var2, command=checkbutton_value2).pack()

        var3 = IntVar()
        dif_button3 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Hard  ", variable=var3, command=checkbutton_value3).pack()

        var4 = IntVar()
        dif_button4 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Insane", variable=var4, command=checkbutton_value4).pack()

        quit_button = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=quit, font=MEDIUM_FONT).pack(fill=X, side = BOTTOM)


###Addition Page

class AdditionPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):


        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text = "Mathmatics Problems Quiz", font=LARGE_FONT).pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text = "Mathematic Equation program", font=MEDIUM_FONT).pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        label3 = tk.Label(self, text = "You have Selected Addition as The Unit", font=SMALL_FONT).pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Reselect Unit", font=MEDIUM_FONT,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage)).pack(fill=X)

        label = Label(self,text="").pack()
        label = Label(self,text="").pack()

        #-----THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE EQUATION TO SHOW IN THE LABEL BELOW-----#

        question_label = Label(self, text="Enter Your Answer", font=MEDIUM_FONT ).pack()
        label = Label(self,text="").pack()

        self.entrytext = StringVar()
        Entry(self, textvariable=self.entrytext, font=MEDIUM_FONT,).pack(fill=X)

        label = Label(self,text="").pack()
        label = Label(self,text="").pack()
        submit_button = tk.Button(self, text = "Submit Answer", font=MEDIUM_FONT).pack(fill=X)

        quit_button = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=quit, font=MEDIUM_FONT,).pack(fill=X, side = BOTTOM)

####Subtraction Page

class SubtractionPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text = "Mathmatics Problems Quiz", font=LARGE_FONT).pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text = "Mathematic Equation program", font=MEDIUM_FONT).pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        label3 = tk.Label(self, text = "You have Selected Subtraction as The Unit", font=SMALL_FONT).pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Reselect Unit", font=MEDIUM_FONT,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage)).pack(fill=X)

        label = Label(self,text="").pack()
        label = Label(self,text="").pack()

        #-----THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE EQUATION TO SHOW IN THE LABEL BELOW-----#

        question_label = Label(self, text="Enter Your Answer", font=MEDIUM_FONT ).pack()
        label = Label(self,text="").pack()

        self.entrytext = StringVar()
        Entry(self, textvariable=self.entrytext, font=MEDIUM_FONT,).pack(fill=X)

        label = Label(self,text="").pack()
        label = Label(self,text="").pack()
        submit_button = tk.Button(self, text = "Submit Answer", font=MEDIUM_FONT).pack(fill=X)

        quit_button = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=quit, font=MEDIUM_FONT,).pack(fill=X, side = BOTTOM)

###Multiply Page

class MultiplicationPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text = "Mathmatics Problems Quiz", font=LARGE_FONT).pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text = "Mathematic Equation program", font=MEDIUM_FONT).pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        label3 = tk.Label(self, text = "You have Selected Multiplication as The Unit", font=SMALL_FONT).pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Reselect Unit", font=MEDIUM_FONT,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage)).pack(fill=X)

        label = Label(self,text="").pack()
        label = Label(self,text="").pack()

        #-----THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE EQUATION TO SHOW IN THE LABEL BELOW-----#

        question_label = Label(self, text="Enter Your Answer", font=MEDIUM_FONT ).pack()
        label = Label(self,text="").pack()

        self.entrytext = StringVar()
        Entry(self, textvariable=self.entrytext, font=MEDIUM_FONT,).pack(fill=X)

        label = Label(self,text="").pack()
        label = Label(self,text="").pack()
        submit_button = tk.Button(self, text = "Submit Answer", font=MEDIUM_FONT).pack(fill=X)

        quit_button = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=quit, font=MEDIUM_FONT,).pack(fill=X, side = BOTTOM)

###Division Page

class DivisionPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text = "Mathmatics Problems Quiz", font=LARGE_FONT).pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text = "Mathematic Equation program", font=MEDIUM_FONT).pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        label3 = tk.Label(self, text = "You have Selected Division as The Unit", font=SMALL_FONT).pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Reselect Unit", font=MEDIUM_FONT,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage)).pack(fill=X)

        label = Label(self,text="").pack()
        label = Label(self,text="").pack()

        #-----THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE EQUATION TO SHOW IN THE LABEL BELOW-----#

        question_label = Label(self, text="Enter Your Answer", font=MEDIUM_FONT ).pack()
        label = Label(self,text="").pack()

        self.entrytext = StringVar()
        Entry(self, textvariable=self.entrytext, font=MEDIUM_FONT,).pack(fill=X)

        label = Label(self,text="").pack()
        label = Label(self,text="").pack()
        submit_button = tk.Button(self, text = "Submit Answer", font=MEDIUM_FONT).pack(fill=X)

        quit_button = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=quit, font=MEDIUM_FONT,).pack(fill=X, side = BOTTOM)



app = ourprogramclass()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for you to understand kinds of `*Var`s.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


class MainPanel(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        # first setup two StringVars. They will be linked to a Label and an Entry widget.
        # we should keep a reference to these two StringVars, because we will call their method
        # to read/write widget content.
        self.msg2show = StringVar()
        self.text_input = StringVar()

        # this is a fixed Label widget whose display will no change.
        # No need to keep a reference(meaning to assign it to a variable).
        Label(self, text='If you click the button, the text in the entry widget will show above.').pack()

        # this is a variable Label widget whose display is decided by the linked variable `self.msg2show`
        Label(self, textvariable=self.msg2show).pack()

        # this is a variable Entry widget whose content is saved into `self.text_input`
        Entry(self, textvariable=self.text_input).pack()

        # this is the button who will trigger `self.set_msg` on click.
        Button(self, text='Set message', command=self.set_msg).pack()

    def set_msg(self):
        # get out what in the Entry widget through calling the `get()` method of `self.text_input`
        text_in_entry_widget = self.text_input.get()
        # and print it into console, for checking.
        print(text_in_entry_widget)

        # then we set that text into self.msg2show, and since it is linked with the variable Label widget
        # the display of that Label will then be set to text_in_entry_widget.
        self.msg2show.set(text_in_entry_widget)

        # You can see here I print the `text_in_entry_widget` to console as well as to a Label.
        # You can do it in the same way.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    MainPanel(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks so much for that. reading that made me understand that alot andddd i actually got it working to display the answer as a label below each time its submitted!!!! you are a legend!! appreciate all the help you have given!! i have looked at PyQt but unfortunately for this 7th form standard we were not aloud to use PyQT we had to use tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

First, the logic carried by those checkbuttons for difficulty selection can be replaced by radio button. It will reduce much code.

Second, you can extract the logic shared by the four equation pages into a base class, and inherit that base class to create the four equation pages.

As for your question, I think it can be put in some method of the base class, this is the code I modified.

The book [Programming Python] covers tkinter very well, and this website http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/contents.htm provides details for tk.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk #css kind of thing for tkinter
import random

dif_enum = ['Easy', 'Medium', 'Hard', 'Insane']
current_difficulty = dif_enum[0]

NUM_QUESTIONS = 10

LARGE_FONT = ("Times New Roman", 25)
MEDIUM_FONT = ("Times New Roman", 15)
SMALL_FONT = ("Times New Roman", 10)


###Base Code For Pages
class ourprogramclass(tk.Tk):

    def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="mathsicon.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Mathematic Equation program")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, AdditionPage, SubtractionPage, MultiplicationPage, DivisionPage ):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


###Page Classes front page
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text = "Mathmatics Problems Quiz", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text = "Mathematic Equation program", font=MEDIUM_FONT)
        label3 = tk.Label(self, text = "Select Your Operation and Difficulty Level", font=SMALL_FONT)
        label1.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        label2.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        label3.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Addition Equations", font=MEDIUM_FONT,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(AdditionPage)).pack(fill=X)
        label = Label(self,text="").pack()
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text = "Subtraction Equations", font=MEDIUM_FONT,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(SubtractionPage)).pack(fill=X)
        label = Label(self,text="").pack()
        button3 = tk.Button(self, text = "Multiplication Equations", font=MEDIUM_FONT,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MultiplicationPage)).pack(fill=X)
        label = Label(self,text="").pack()
        button4 = tk.Button(self, text = "Division Equations", font=MEDIUM_FONT,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(DivisionPage)).pack(fill=X)
        label = Label(self,text="").pack()

        label4 = tk.Label(self, text = "Select Difficulty", font=LARGE_FONT).pack()

        # @etuc_comment:Use `Radiobutton` for the "select one from many" logic. It takes only a few lines.
        difficulty = tk.StringVar(value=dif_enum[0])

        def show_and_set_difficulty():
            global current_difficulty
            current_difficulty = difficulty.get()
            print(1 + dif_enum.index(difficulty.get()), difficulty.get())

        for dif in dif_enum:
            tk.Radiobutton(self, text=dif, value=dif, variable=difficulty, command=show_and_set_difficulty).pack()

        quit_button = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=quit, font=MEDIUM_FONT).pack(fill=X, side = BOTTOM)


class EquationPageBase(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, equal_type):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        tk.Label(self, text="Mathmatics Problems Quiz", font=LARGE_FONT).pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        tk.Label(self, text="Mathematic Equation program", font=MEDIUM_FONT).pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        # @etuc_comment: Use the third parameter `equal_type` for displaying current equation type.
        tk.Label(self, text="You have Selected {} as The Unit".format(equal_type), font=SMALL_FONT).pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        tk.Button(self, text="Reselect Unit", font=MEDIUM_FONT,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage)).pack(fill=X)

        Label(self,text="").pack()
        Label(self,text="").pack()

        #-----THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE EQUATION TO SHOW IN THE LABEL BELOW-----#
        self.submit_counter = 0
        self.correct_counter = 0
        self.equation_strvar = tk.StringVar(value='')
        Label(self, textvariable=self.equation_strvar, font=MEDIUM_FONT).pack()
        Label(self,text="").pack()

        self.answer_strvar = StringVar()
        Entry(self, textvariable=self.answer_strvar, font=MEDIUM_FONT, ).pack(fill=X)

        Label(self,text="").pack()
        Label(self,text="").pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Submit Answer", font=MEDIUM_FONT, command=self.submit).pack(fill=X)

        tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=quit, font=MEDIUM_FONT,).pack(fill=X, side = BOTTOM)

        self.update_equation()

    def update_equation(self):
        self.equation = self.gen_equal()
        self.equation_strvar.set('Enter Your Answer For: {}'.format(self.equation))
        self.answer_strvar.set('')

    def gen_equal(self):
        """
        Subclasses will overload this method to generate the proper equation according to difficulty and
        equation type setting. See an example in the `AdditionPage`
        :return: Should return the equation as string. e.g. "1 + 2"
        """
        pass

    def submit(self):
        try:
            user_answer = int(self.answer_strvar.get())
        except:
            return

        if eval(self.equation) == user_answer:
            print('Correct')
            self.correct_counter += 1
        else:
            print('Error: {} != {}, answer is {}'.format(self.equation, user_answer, eval(self.equation)))

        self.submit_counter += 1
        if self.submit_counter < NUM_QUESTIONS:
            self.update_equation()
        else:
            self.show_result()

            self.submit_counter = 0
            self.correct_counter = 0

    def show_result(self):
        print('{} questions, {} correct.'.format(NUM_QUESTIONS, self.correct_counter))


# Addition Page
class AdditionPage(EquationPageBase):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        EquationPageBase.__init__(self, parent, controller, equal_type='Addition')

    def gen_equal(self):
        """
        This is an example for addition.
        """
        if current_difficulty == 'Easy':
            return '{} + {}'.format(random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10))
        elif current_difficulty == 'Medium':
            return '{} + {}'.format(random.randint(10, 25), random.randint(10, 25))
        elif current_difficulty == 'Hard':
            return '{} + {}'.format(random.randint(25, 50), random.randint(25, 50))
        elif current_difficulty == 'Insane':
            return '{} + {}'.format(random.randint(50, 100), random.randint(50, 100))
        else:
            raise ValueError('Wrong difficulty')


# Subtraction Page
class SubtractionPage(EquationPageBase):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        EquationPageBase.__init__(self, parent, controller, equal_type='Subtraction')

    def gen_equal(self):
        pass


# Multiply Page
class MultiplicationPage(EquationPageBase):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        EquationPageBase.__init__(self, parent, controller, equal_type='Multiplication')

    def gen_equal(self):
        pass


# Division Page
class DivisionPage(EquationPageBase):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        EquationPageBase.__init__(self, parent, controller, equal_type='Division')

    def gen_equal(self):
        pass


app = ourprogramclass()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for that. the logic behind your editing and my work is alot smoother running. Like i said im still pretty new to tkinter (only started that this year) so that has help alot!! i will finish off the code and now complete it in a more structural manner :) again thanks for the help. I also appreciate the comments you have left in it explaining what is happening in what code and/or what its there for!! :)

Comment: Hi, I see your confusion on there. If you want to display something on the GUI, the simplest way is to use a Label widget. You can setup a StringVar(), like `self.msg2show = tk.StringVar(value='hello world')`, then link this variable to a Label widget: `Lable(..., textvariable=self.msg2show, ...).pack()`. Then you can use `self.msg2show.set('new message will display on that label')` to update the content of the label widget. the `text` parameter is no longer needed for that label anymore in this case.

Comment: can you check the new answer ive stuck up to make sure im doing this correct. :)

Comment: Well, actually you should put the `self.msg2show = tk.StringVar(...)` in the `__init__` method of `EquationPageBase`. You should setup the `Label(self, textvariable=self.msg2show).pack()` right after it, don't use `Label=Label(...)`, there is no need to assign the Label widget to a variable if we don't use it after. And use `self.msg2show.set('a message')` **instead of** `print('a message')` (see where you've commented out). Retry it. Link a *Var(StringVar, IntVar, FloatVar) to a widget then you can operate the widget through that *Var, that's how tkinter works.

Comment: okay so by putting the `self.msg2show.set('a message')` in the addition page is what i want, but what i want it to display is whats been produced in the `submit definition`. so the label will be below the submit button saying to the user if they got it correct or not, and then at the end saying well done you got this many correct out of this many (as ive tweaked the above code) would'nt putting that function in the `__init__` of the `EquationPageBase` defeat the purpose of getting the answer from the `submit definition`. sorry as said earlier im still pretty new to tkinter and python.. :/

Comment: I posted an example for you to understand the StringVar mechanism in tkinter. Check it, and I would suggest again for you to read Mark's two excellent python books: Learning Python and Programming Python. The latter covers tkinter well. It will lead you in to the tkinter world. However, after a year and a half working with tkinter, I would suggest you not to go too deep into tkinter, since it lacks document and advance widgets. It fits small applications but not for large program. In any case, PyQT is the better GUI choice for Pythoner, even if it's much harder at the beginning.